# Access denied when I try to install profiler

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2016

As the subject says, I am having an issue trying to install profiler through Plugin Registration Tool. I can do all actions on plugins from registration to disabling them.  
I am using Microsoft Dynamics® **CRM 2016** (8.1.0.359) (DB 8.1.0.359) On-premises, and **Registration tool version is 8.2.1.8676 64bit**.

**What I have tried:**
I tried tp install profiler in Dev, and staging environment but no luck! 
I tried to install it on 100% running plugins and still same issue.

Any idea how to solve this problem or an approach to find the source of the problem?

**Note**: I am a system administrator and deploy admin too.

Many thanks,

```
Unhandled Exception: System.Exception: Solution Import Failed: 31 Unhandled Exception: System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[[Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OrganizationServiceFault, Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]]: Access is denied.Detail: 
<OrganizationServiceFault xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts">
  <ErrorCode>-2147187707</ErrorCode>
  <ErrorDetails xmlns:d2p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic" />
  <Message>Access is denied.</Message>
  <Timestamp>2017-10-03T18:53:01.8969526Z</Timestamp>
  <InnerFault>
    <ErrorCode>-2147187707</ErrorCode>
    <ErrorDetails xmlns:d3p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic" />
    <Message>Access is denied.</Message>
    <Timestamp>2017-10-03T18:53:01.8969526Z</Timestamp>
    <InnerFault>
      <ErrorCode>-2147220970</ErrorCode>
      <ErrorDetails xmlns:d4p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic" />
      <Message>System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Microsoft Dynamics CRM has experienced an error. Reference number for administrators or support: #D6978376</Message>
      <Timestamp>2017-10-03T18:53:01.8969526Z</Timestamp>
      <InnerFault i:nil="true" />
      <TraceText i:nil="true" />
    </InnerFault>
    <TraceText i:nil="true" />
  </InnerFault>
  <TraceText i:nil="true" />
</OrganizationServiceFault>
   at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.OrganizationSdkServiceInternal.Execute(OrganizationRequest request, CorrelationToken correlationToken, CallerOriginToken callerOriginToken, WebServiceType serviceType, Boolean checkAdminMode, ExecutionContext executionContext)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.InprocessServiceProxy.ExecuteCore(OrganizationRequest request)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Asynchronous.ExecuteSdkMessageOperation.InternalExecute(AsyncEvent asyncEvent)
   at PluginProfiler.Library.ProfilerManagementUtility.ImportSolutionAsyncAndWait(CrmServiceClient service, String prtpath, Boolean publishWorkflows, Boolean overwriteUnmanagedCustomizations, Int32 sleepInterval, Int32 asyncWaitTimeout)
   at PluginProfiler.Library.ProfilerManagementUtility.RetrieveOrCreateProfilerPluginType(CrmServiceClient service, String prtpath)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Tools.Libraries.OrganizationHelper.InstallProfiler(CrmOrganization org, String prtPath)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Tools.PluginRegistration.OrganizationControlViewModel.<>c__DisplayClass27.<InstallProfiler_Clicked>b__1f(Object o, DoWorkEventArgs e)
```

Answer (score 1):

We were able to solve this thanks to Jens @Dynamics-community

The solution was by modifying the permissions to folder c:\Program Files\Microsoft Dynamics CRM\CustomizationImport.

Detailed answer can be found here: https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/117/p/253323/710772#710772

Thanks all,

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to downgrade the version of the profiler you are using? Going from 8.1 to 8.2 has quite a big gap on the functionalities that have been changed.
If you are on premise are you sure you have the correct AD groups assigned to your user? Is not enough to insert your user in the deployment admin tab in the deployment manager.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the exact issue, What worked for me is Installing Plugin profiler with Dynamics CRM Solution. You will have a .zip file with name "PluginProfiler.Solution.zip" for plugin profiler. Try importing it and should work.

Let me know if it works for you